# Contact form 7 : multiple lines of javascript on submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I need use Contact 7 to have an embedded form that submits the info to my Viral Loops account.

It needs to run the following code once the form is submitted, i.e `on_sent_ok:`

```
VL.options.form_fields.form_firstName = $("#firstname").val(); //capture the first name
VL.options.form_fields.form_email = $("#email").val(); //capture the email
VL.options.form_fields.form_lastName = $("#lastname").val(); //capture the last name (if applicable in your form)
//submit the participant to Viral Loops
VL.createLead(function() {
//any logic to run after the participation
});
```

I don't know where or how to add it, because **you can only have one line of code using on sent ok in the advanced settings.**

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: It's not the most readable, but why not just put all your js on one line, then? Semicolons will take care of distinguishing the end of any one statement.

Comment: That or you could put it as a function in an external JS file that you have enqueued (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and call the function from on_sent_ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, either minify it:

```
on_sent_ok: "VL.options.form_fields.form_firstName = $('#firstname').val();VL.options.form_fields.form_email = $('#email').val();VL.options.form_fields.form_lastName = $('#lastname').val();VL.createLead(function() {});"
```

---

Or you could create a JavaScript file in your (child)theme directory in `js/script.js`, and then add this to the `functions.php` in your (child)theme directory:

```
/**
 * Enqueue a script with jQuery as a dependency.
 */
function so_40916565_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'so-40916565', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_40916565_enqueue' );
```

and in your newly created javascript file:

```
function js_40916565() {
  VL.options.form_fields.form_firstName = $("#firstname").val(); //capture the first name
  VL.options.form_fields.form_email = $("#email").val(); //capture the email
  VL.options.form_fields.form_lastName = $("#lastname").val(); //capture the last name (if applicable in your form)
  //submit the participant to Viral Loops
  VL.createLead(function() {
    //any logic to run after the participation
  });
}
```

And in your contact form 7:

```
on_sent_ok: "js_40916565();"
```

I haven't actually tested it, so if it doesn't work right out of the box, leave a comment.

Comment: It's not working :(

Should my js have this at the start?
`<?php

/**
 * Enqueue `

If it helps these are my contact 7 fields
`<p>[text* firstname placeholder "First Name*"]</p>
<p></p>
<p>[text* lastname placeholder "Last Name*"]</p>
<p></p>
<p>[email* email placeholder "Email Address*"]</p>
<p></p>
<p>[text* country  placeholder "Country*"]</p>
<p></p>
<p>[submit "Send"]</p>` I also added the country line into the script `VL.options.form_fields.form_country = $("#country").val(); //capture the country (if applicable in your form)`

Comment: No, sorry.  Perhaps my post isn't clear enough.  The code in the `function js_40916565` block should be in your `js/script.js` file, nothing more (unless the file already existed).  The `Enqueue a script with jQuery as a dependency` block should be in your `functions.php` file, and the on_sent_ok should obviously be in Contact Form 7 in the WordPress admin.

Comment: Yes I've done that but I'm using The Gem theme, which has custom js in the theme options - I added the `function` bit there. The `enqueue` bit is in my functions.php file, in the file there was already the `<?php` - if i delete it a get an error at the top of the website. `On sent ok` bit in the contact 7 advanced settings. Here's the page if it helps [link] (http://sportshosts.com/home-13-2)

Comment: Yes, that link does help.  Since you have added the javascript function in the theme options, there is no need to add the code in the `functions.php` file, in fact you should delete the code from functions.php since the web site tries to load a file `js/script.js` that does not exist.  Finally, you have not updated the code in your Contact Form 7.  Change the on_sent_ok to `on_sent_ok: "js_40916565();"`.  You're nearly there!  Oh, and you're going to have to add IDs to your CF7 fields.  Example `[email* email id:EMAIL placeholder "Email Address*"]`

Comment: Still no luck. The guys at viral loops gave me some js code
`function js_40916565() {
  VL.options.form_fields.form_firstName = jQuery("#firstname").val();
  VL.options.form_fields.form_email = jQuery("#email").val(); 
  VL.options.form_fields.form_lastName = jQuery("#lastname").val();
  VL.extraData["rNk0t3ZC"] = jQuery("#country").val();
  VL.createLead(function() {
    //any logic to run after the participation
  });
}`
Annnd i took out the stuff from the functions file.

Comment: Are you missing the on_ok_sent in your Conact Form 7?  I don't find it in your code.  They guys at Viral Loops gave you the code from my post just above, if that is what they sent you.  :)  You should have to put `on_sent_ok: "js_40916565();"` in your Contact Form 7 scripts.

Comment: Yeah they adapted yours! Got it working now. Thank you so much!

On a side note, any idea how to add a border to the field forms? I added this in but it doesn't seem to have worked: `.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.wpcf7 input[type="email"],
{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #404040;
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #ff990a;
}`

Comment: You are *really* close.  You've just got to make your CSS a little more important than the others, and remove the trailing comma after the email input.  `.wpcf7 .wpcf7-form input[type="text"], .wpcf7 .wpcf7-form input[type="email"] { background-color: #f9f9f9; color: #404040; width: 50%; border: 2px solid #ff990a; }`.  If you wish, you can mark the question as solved by clicking on the checkbox.